# Can't get values from api as double or int

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing this problem where I can't return a value from my API as a double.

```
 Future<int> getStock(String refProd) async {
int stok = 0;
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/produit/stock/$refProd"),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  setState(() {
    stok = jsonDecode(response.body);
  });
  return stok;
} else {
  throw Exception('DB ERROR!');
}
```

}

Trying to print it like this :

```
print(getstock('1200').toString());
```

It returns : `InstanceofFuture<int>` but not the returned value which is `stok` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
int stock= await getStock('1200');
```

or directly

```
print(await getstock('1200').toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is `async` and therefore returns a `Future`. You could `await` the result of `getStock` before using it, like so:

```
print(await getstock('1200').toString());
```